# lucene multiple documents created for large and unique number of resources?

Tags: lucene

I am a beginner in lucene search.If I have a collection resources like:
id,name,{list of products},{list of keywords}.If I want to search based on name or products or keyword.I have some doubts related to lucene and its usage:
1)For document creation, I create a document that has the structure of id,name,products(multiple values),keywords(multiple values).If I have a thousand unique resources, will it create 1000 unique documents? 
2)Also, If I make name and products field as searchable fields(as StringField), then after searching, will the result also contains(ScoreDocs contains) exactly the same set of documents that has the text I searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q>** <..> will it create 1000 unique documents?
**A>** Lucene doesn't have the concept of "uniqueness" - it is only in your head. Alternatively, think of this as if all documents are unique for Lucene. If you search by these fields, relevant documents will be returned.

**Q>** <..> will the result also contains(ScoreDocs contains) exactly the same set of documents that has the text I searched?
**A>** Strange/unclear question. If you search for *all* documents, you will get *all* documents. If your search query will only match *some* documents, *some* documents will be returned. The internals are more complex - it all depends on how you analyze the text. Maybe you can more give concrete example with use cases?

Comment: I wanted to know whether my understanding is correct about the lucene indexing and searching.So, in this case,If I have thousand resources, how many documents will be created by lucene?

Comment: You have explicit control on how many documents will be created. This will be as much as how many `org.apache.lucene.document.Document` instances you will create and write using `IndexWriter`. If you create a document per each resource (which seems most sensible), then yes, there will be thousand documents.